# how to pause ,stop volume and mute a video without using media controller?

Tags: video-streaming, android-videoview, android-video-player, mediacontroller

I want to pause mute volume a video on button without using media controller.
I'm using the following code:

```
sound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//
//            }
//        });
//        mute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//
//            }
//        });
//        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//
//            }
//        });
//        pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
////                videoView.pause();
//            }
//        });
```

But I don't want to do on these button clicks.
Please help me to sort it out.

Comment: Really need more code and reasons for decision making.

Comment: :( i dont have more code .. i just want to pause a video that is playing from raw folder .

Comment: without using media controller how can it be done?

Comment: I can only read a block of commented codes.

Comment: im using this code to pause a video without using media controller but its not working pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onPause();
            }
        });@Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        try {
            if (videoView != null) {
                int position = videoView.getCurrentPosition();
                videoView.pause();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }